# Unity SendKeys to launch Google Assistant via Win+Shift+A

Tags: c#

So I've done some coding with unity previously but trying to do traditional coding and am having trouble figuring it out.

After downloading Google Assistant on my Windows 10 computer, it does not listen to "Ok google". So I decided that a simple project was to make a program that would listen for a keyword and would stimulate the keys: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open Google Assistant.

The current code I have is here:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using WindowsInput;

namespace Ok_Google
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        string keyWord1 = "Ok Google";
        string keyWord2 = "Hey Google";
        private object SendKeys;

        public void Start()
        { 
        }

        public void ListeForKeyWord()
        {

        }
        public void EnterShortCut()
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{LWin}");
            SendKeys.Send("{Shift}");
            SendKeys.Send("{A}");
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not recognizing the Object Send, following the command SendKeys

Can anyone find a potential solution for this and show the process of correcting these errors?

Comment: Please read [ask], esp. the **Write a title that summarizes the specific problem** section. Also see [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to learn how to better format code in your question.

Comment: `SendKeys` is a plain `object` which obviously does not have a `Send` method ... Are you looking for [SendKeys::Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send)? But this will only work in a WinForms application. Otherwise have you tried reading the docs for [WindowsInput](https://github.com/MediatedCommunications/WindowsInput)

Comment: You should tag this with the relevant framework. Also you could just fix your GA config rather than trying to make an app to launch a link that already launches an app...

Comment: just FYI, AutoHotkey is fantastic for doing this kind of thing